# TRIM on encrypted device with Precise

Tags: encryption, ssd, pam, trim

I have migrated the main data to a new SSD. (Samsung 840 EVO, 120GB.) My `~` is an encrypted partition automounted by `pam_mount`. That is, there is a record in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` for this partition.

I want it to support TRIM. I know that it weakens the encryption a bit (i.e. establishes some kind of side-channel), but I hope it is acceptable.

I've tried to enable it in `pam_mount.conf.xml`. One approach was to include `discard` to mount options, which was said to automagically allow discard on the encrypted block device:

```
<volume user="{USERNAME}" fstype="crypt" mountpoint="/home/{USERNAME}" path="/dev/sdb{NUMBER}"  options="defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,discard" />
```

Another attempt was to include `discard` (and also `discards`) in the mntoptions.

```
<mntoptions allow="discard,discards,nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
```

No luck. The fstrim still does not work:

```
% sudo fstrim --verbose ~                        
fstrim: /home/{USERNAME}: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

Have I forgotten anything? Would an upgrade to 14.04 solve the problem? The `man cryptsetup` command tells me that `--allow-discards` is supported, so I hope it should work. Kernel version is `3.13.0-35-generic`, which seems to be OK, since version `3.1+` is required.

The underlying filesystem is ext4. The `fstrim` command works perfectly fine with unencrypted filesystems (that are also ext4), but does not work with the filesystem that is wrapped by dm-crypt (?) encryption.

Note that the `discard` mount option seems to be used:

```
% mount | grep ~
/dev/sdb{NUMBER} on /home/{USERNAME} type crypt (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and state which filesystem you are using.

Comment: - do not use discard; it will kill your SSD - see `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` to turn fstrim on.

Comment: Well, I wanted to use fstrim, but I was not able to make it working, as described. So I tried to allow discards. I've read somewhere that it (pam_mount or dm-crypt) autodetects the need to use '--allow-discards' from the discard option.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a new version of `pam-mount` from source did the trick. I had to install a `.deb` of `libhx28` and `libhx-dev` from Trusty (which is risky in general) in order to get a newer version of this library.

You will probably have the newer version in a newer Ubuntu out of box, so you can skip compiling. If you can, you can upgrade to Trusty. I want to stay with Precise some time.

Now, enabling `allow_discards` without `discard` is an ugly hack. The [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/feature-requests/26/) just checks for the presence of a "discard" flag. So, I decided to put both "discard" and "nodiscard" (in this order) and hope it will do the trick.

Now `fstrim` on this device works but I hope discard mount flag is ineffective. Not sure if I can test it.

Alternatively, one might try to do some remounting, but I did not succeed with this approach.